# How to guarantee the uniqueness of gae datastore Name/ID?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
class Post(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='posts')
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    desc = db.TextProperty()
    def addApplication(self, user, message, contact_info=""):
         new_app = TaskApplication(parent=self, user=user, message=message, contact_info=contact_info)
         new_app.put()

class Application(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='applications')
    contact_info = db.StringProperty()
    message = db.TextProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

So I have these entities and when I add an application entity, I always set the parent to Post. Please see the addApplication function above.

However, every time when I created an application. The Name/ID in the datastore will create id=1(see the image below), which I thought gae will create a unique number like 39001 every time.

Is there a way I can ensure the uniqueness of this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow GAE to create them for you as you are doing, **they will be unique.**

However the parent is also considered, so the sequence of entities beginning with a root entity and proceeding from parent to child, leading to a given entity, constitute that entity's ancestor path.

The complete key identifying an entity thus consists of a sequence of kind-identifier pairs specifying its ancestor path and terminating with those of the entity itself.

So if you were to manually generate those ids manually you could use something like this to allocate 100 IDs for entities with parent key p:

```
first, last = MyModel.allocate_ids(100, parent=p)
```

Note the parent is included. So you could run this later for parent q:

```
first, last = MyModel.allocate_ids(100, parent=q)
```

And although some of the ID's returned might be the same number they don't reference the same model because the parent is considered also (which you implement in this example).

More here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities

Comment: If you see my above image, you can see ID/Name are id=1, why is that happening?

Comment: Because that's only showing you the last component of the key. As Paul says, it's unique once you take into account the whole path from the parent, which you'll see once you click through.

Comment: Probably worth reading up on Kinds and Identifiers https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Kinds_and_Identifiers

Comment: So the short answer to how to guarantee uniqueness is simply to let the system manage the IDs for you.

Comment: @tipsywacky One more thing.. `TaskApplication.get_by_id(1)` won't return anything unless you're going to provide a `parent`.. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_id